# is there an optional end-instruction in rebol/red like ";" in javascript

Tags: rebol, red

red accepts instruction written on multiple lines which is good. But is there a way to use separator between instructions ?

I tried to use ";" but it doesn't work, is there any other symbol available ?

Comment: In Rebol2/R3-Alpha, UNSET! is generally a no-op in instructions like **any** and **all**.  So you can do something like **|: does []**.  That will not work in Red, as it considers UNSET! to be truthy in an ANY and ALL.  So **any [1 > 2 | "foo"]** will be UNSET!, not "foo".  For related topics, see [BAR!](https://trello.com/c/7RbcHZX3/128-vertical-bar-is-an-expression-barrier-which-can-be-used-to-isolate-evaluations) and [null](https://trello.com/c/rmsTJueg)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no such symbol and it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> red accepts instruction written on multiple lines which is good. But is there a way to use separator between instructions ?

There are no "instructions" in Red, it's all *data* (blocks, words, integers, strings, etc...). Moreover, "lines" are irrevelant in Red once your script is `load`-ed in memory, it becomes a native data structure that you can interact with, like any other data structure. New-line characters are converted to so-called "line markers" that are just cosmetic, they have no specific meaning in the language. They separate *values* like any other accepted whitespace character.

If you really need to make a long expression easier to read, you can use "line markers" or parens to isolate nested expressions.

Comment: It looks `load` mostly keeps the line markers in the given string.